# Encountered - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'posts') while trying to access data from a JSON file using Express(Node.js)

Tags: node.js, json, express, rest, web-development-server

While trying to access data from data.json file, I got an error -  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'posts') in the second route handler, whereas, I got no error in the first route handler.

```
const data = require('./data.json')

app.get('/r/:subreddit', (req, res) => { //first route handler
    const { subreddit } = req.params
    console.log(data[subreddit].posts) //no error
    res.render('subreddit', { sub: data[subreddit] })
})

app.get('/r/:subreddit/:postId/comments', (req, res) => { //second route handler
    const { subreddit, postId } = req.params
    const post = data[subreddit].posts.find(post => post.id === parseInt(postId)) //error
    res.render('comments/index', { post })
})
```

A jist of data.json -

```
{
"mightyharvest": {
        "name": "Mighty Harvest",
        "subscribers": 44002,
        "description": "Feeding many villages and village idiots for 10s of days.",
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": 301,
                "title": "My first meyer lemon ripened today. Im so proud of the little guy. Banana for scale",
                "author": "proudmamma",
                "img": "https://preview.redd.it/1bz6we4j54941.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a036ea99299f7737efde9f6c3bfa43893f5eaa00",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "author": "xyz",
                        "text": "LOLOL!"
                    },
                    {
                        "author": "abc",
                        "text": "ROFL!"
                    }
                ]
            }
}
```

I tried using app.use(express.json()) and also app.use(bodyParser.json()), but still got the same error.
The first route handler works properly but the second route handler shows error.

Comment: Which value do you send as :subreddit and :postId

Comment: I manually created an anchor tag to go to a particular subreddit in first route, and in the second route I'm sending the name and id of the subreddit from the first route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was sending `subreddit.name` from `data.json` to the second route, which also contained spaces and capital letters because of which `data[subreddit]` was not a defined property of `data.json` and was shown as undefined.
Eg: instead of `data[mightyharvest]`, it read as `data[Mighty Harvest]`.
So I need to remove the spaces and convert it to lower case while sending a request from the first route to the second route, which I did by changing -

```
<a href="/r/<%= sub.name %>/<%= post.id %>/comments">
```

To:

```
<a href="/r/<%= sub.name.split(" ").join("").toLowerCase() %>/<%= post.id %>/comments">
```

While sending a request to the second route. And while sending a request to the first route I manually typed the correct name so it did not show an error.